# ReferenceError: payment is not defined on checkout page

Tags: javascript, magento

I am getting following error on the browser console when I am on checkout page.

```
ReferenceError: payment is not defined
```

When I click on the **credit card payment option no Form is opened to enter card details** and above mentioned error is thrown.

For the Credit card authorize.net option in Magento admin is being used.I am also using the paypal express checkout

I have following code in the `template\checkout\onepage\payment\methods.phtml` file

```
    <dl class="sp-methods" id="checkout-payment-method-load">
<?php
    $methods = $this->getMethods();
    $oneMethod = count($methods) <= 1;
?>
 <?php echo $this->getfieldshtml(1); ?>
<?php
    foreach ($methods as $_method):
        $_code = $_method->getCode();
?>
    <dt>
    <?php if(!$oneMethod): ?>
        <input id="p_method_<?php echo $_code ?>" value="<?php echo $_code ?>" type="radio" name="payment[method]" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_method->getTitle()) ?>" onclick="payment.switchMethod('<?php echo $_code ?>')"<?php if($this->getSelectedMethodCode()==$_code): ?> checked="checked"<?php endif; ?> class="radio" />
    <?php else: ?>
        <span class="no-display"><input id="p_method_<?php echo $_code ?>" value="<?php echo $_code ?>" type="radio" name="payment[method]" checked="checked" class="radio" /></span>
        <?php $oneMethod = $_code; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
        <label for="p_method_<?php echo $_code ?>"><?php echo $this->getMethodTitle($_method) ?> <?php echo $this->getMethodLabelAfterHtml($_method) ?></label>
    </dt>
    <?php if ($html = $this->getPaymentMethodFormHtml($_method)): ?>
    <dd>
        <?php echo $html; ?>
    </dd>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php echo $this->getfieldshtml(2); ?>
    <?php echo $this->getfieldshtml(3); ?>
</dl>
<?php echo $this->getChildChildHtml('additional'); ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
//function obsrv(id){
//    if(id && id!=null){
//      $$("#"+id+" input,#"+id+" label,#"+id+" select").each(function(onebyone){if($(onebyone.id) && $(onebyone.id)!=null){$(onebyone.id).removeAttribute("disabled");}});
//    }
//  }


<?php echo $this->getChildChildHtml('scripts'); ?>

$$("#co-payment-form input,#co-payment-form select").each(function(onebyone){if($(onebyone.id) && $(onebyone.id)!=null && onebyone.name.startsWith('fm_fields')){if(true){$(onebyone.id).removeAttribute("disabled");}}});

<?php if (is_string($oneMethod)): ?>
    payment.switchMethod('<?php echo $oneMethod ?>');
<?php endif; ?>
//]]>
</script>
```

I replaced the code with following because this is there in Magento default code file also

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
    <?php echo $this->getChildChildHtml('scripts'); ?>
    payment.init();
    <?php if (is_string($oneMethod)): ?>
    payment.switchMethod('<?php echo $oneMethod ?>');
        <?php endif; ?>
    //]]>
</script>
```

But still no luck

Comment: Place your code here. Without having to know your code, we can't say what is the problem you're having.

Comment: what is payment? have you defined it anywhere ?

Comment: I have fixed this using custom jQuery code

Answer (score 0):

replace all payment. by billing. in that file and in osc_payment.js and payment.js of ogone + add this configurable layout :

```
    <checkout_onestep_index>
    <reference name="head">
        <action method="addJs"><script>netresearch/ops/osc_payment.js</script></action>
        <action method="addJs"><script>netresearch/ops/payment.js</script></action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="head">
        <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/ops.css</stylesheet></action>
    </reference>
</checkout_onestep_index>
```

Answer (score -1):

I had the same error, maybe for another reason, maybe not, so this is how I've solved it...

We have PHP set to use commas for type "float". But payment.phtml is echoing this :

```
var quoteBaseGrandTotal = <?php echo (float)$this->getQuoteBaseGrandTotal(); ?>;
```

When orders amount is a float as 19,83€ , result is :

```
var quoteBaseGrandTotal = 19,83;
```

This produced the javascript error.

I had not enough time to patch this properly, so I replace the line with :

```
var quoteBaseGrandTotal = <?php echo str_replace(',','.', (float)$this->getQuoteBaseGrandTotal() ); ?>;
```

And the problem disappeared.